# While trying to get user’s list of followed sites. By calling /users/{user-id}/followedSites endpoint gives "General exception while processing”

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, error, microsoft-graph

I was trying to get user’s list of followed sites (using application permissions). But calling `/users/{user-id}/followed` Sites endpoint gives "General exception while processing” error
and not able to know the root cause for this issue. Is something known issue or is it permission related issue?

Please find logs attached for the same:

**Exception Information**:

```
Exception Type: Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException
Error: Code: generalException
Message: General exception while processing
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    date: 2023-01-23T05:01:34
    request-id: 67a395f0-d519-483e-9f0a-6c4b8bd5c8d9
    client-request-id: 67a395f0-d519-483e-9f0a-6c4b8bd5c8d9
ClientRequestId: 67a395f0-d519-483e-9f0a-6c4b8bd5c8d9

ResponseHeaders: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
request-id: 67a395f0-d519-483e-9f0a-6c4b8bd5c8d9
client-request-id: 67a395f0-d519-483e-9f0a-6c4b8bd5c8d9
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Central US","Slice":"E","Ring":"3","ScaleUnit":"001","RoleInstance":"CH01EPF0000730F"}}
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
Date: Mon, 23 Jan 2023 05:01:33 GMT

StatusCode: InternalServerError
RawResponseBody: {"error":{"code":"generalException","message":"General exception while processing","innerError":{"date":"2023-01-23T05:01:34","request-id":"67a395f0-d519-483e-9f0a-6c4b8bd5c8d9","client-request-id":"67a395f0-d519-483e-9f0a-6c4b8bd5c8d9"}}}
Message: Code: generalException
Message: General exception while processing
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    date: 2023-01-23T05:01:34
    request-id: 67a395f0-d519-483e-9f0a-6c4b8bd5c8d9
    client-request-id: 67a395f0-d519-483e-9f0a-6c4b8bd5c8d9
ClientRequestId: 67a395f0-d519-483e-9f0a-6c4b8bd5c8d9

HelpLink: NULL
Source: Microsoft.Graph.Core
HResult: -2146233088
```

**StackTrace Information**:

> at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.d__18.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.d__40.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.d__34`1.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Microsoft.Graph.UserFollowedSitesCollectionWithReferencesRequest.d__1.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Mps.Client.Mfp.Service.Commons.ScanToOneDrive.Implementation.ScanToOneDriveService.d__6.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Mps.Client.Mfp.WebHost.Modules.SharePointModule.d__9.MoveNext()

Comment: I am checking to see if the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/sites-list-followed?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) article, it does not support to get followed site of other users using Application permissions.

[image]

So here you need to use Deleted Flow in authentication